# Adding $\kappa$ Cohen reals, sets of hereditary cardinality $<\kappa$ are in some intermediate model.

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

Suppose $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal and consider the forcing notion $Fn(\kappa,2)$ consisting of finite partials functions from $\kappa$ to $\{0,1\}$. Let $G$ be $Fn(\kappa,2)$-generic over $V$.

Suppose $x\in V[G]$ is of hereditary cardinality $<\kappa.$ I need the following but I haven't been able to argue its truth:

There exists a set $J\subseteq\kappa$ with $|J|<\kappa$ and (identifying $Fn(\kappa,2)\cong Fn(J,2)\times Fn(\kappa\setminus J,2)$) filters $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that $G=G_1\times G_2$ and
\begin{align}
&G_1\text{ is }Fn(J,2)\text{-generic over }V\text{ and }G_2\text{ is }Fn(\kappa\setminus J,2)\text{-generic over }V[G_1];\\
&x\in V[G_1];\text{ and}\\
&V[G]=V[G_1][G_2].
\end{align}

I think I need to find a name for $x$ in $V$ of both hereditary cardinality and rank $<\kappa$, but I've been tying myself into knots over this.

Comment: Tis becomes easier if you observe that $x$ can be coded into a set of ordinals in an absolute way. Fix a bijection between the transitive closure of $x$, TC$(x)$, and some cardinal $\mu<\kappa$. The membership relation on TC$(x)$ corresponds to a binary relation on $\mu$, which you can code, using a pairing function, as a subset $y$ of $\mu$. Now any model that contains $y$ will also contain that binary relation on $\mu$, hence its transitive collapse which is TC$(x)$, and hence $x$. So you need only arrange to get $y\in V[G_1]$.  [continued in next comment]

Comment: Because $y$ is a subset of $\mu$, you can work with the canonical names $\check\alpha$ of ordinals $\alpha<\mu$, avoiding the hassle of complicated names for elements of TC$(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~vfischer/Bachelorarbeit2_Schilhan.pdf) you can see this result (pag 11-12).

For $x\in V$ you need find a nice name and use the ccc property to obtain a upper bound for the size of $J$.

Comment: I imagine you are referring to Lemma 1.31? But that does require that $\mathring{x}$ is a name for a subset of $X\in V$. Which I don't see why we may assume?

Comment: @JKEG See my comments under the question for why you can assume that you're dealing with a subset of the ground model (in fact a set of ordinals).

Answer (score 0):

We first verify the following:

> If $ G$ is generic for $Fn(\kappa,2)$ over $V$, then $H_{\kappa}[G] = H_{\kappa}^{V[G]}$

It is easy to see that $H_{\kappa}[G] \subseteq H_{\kappa}^{V[G]}$. For $\supseteq$  suppose for a contradiction that there is a $\in$-minimal  $x \in H_{\kappa}^{V[G]} \setminus H_{\kappa}[G]$. 
Then $ trcl(x) \subseteq H_{\kappa}[G]$, so for each $ y \in trcl(x) $ we can define $h(y) \in H_{\kappa} \cap V^{\mathbb{P}}$ such that $ h(y)_{G} = y$. Let $ z = \{ h(y) \ | \ y \in trcl(x) \}$, since $ |trcl(\{x\})| =:\theta < \kappa $, $|z| = |x| \leq \theta < \kappa$ it follows that in $V[G]$ there is  a surjection $f:\theta \longrightarrow trcl(\{z\})$.
Let $ \rho $ be a name for $ x $, $\tau$ a name for $z$, $\dot{f}$ a name for $f$  and $p \in G $ such that 
\begin{gather*} p \Vdash \big( \rho \in H_{\kappa}^{V[\dot{G}]} \setminus H_{\kappa}[\dot{G}] \ \& \ \rho \subseteq H_{\xi}[G] \ \& \ \tau \subseteq H_{\xi}  \big)
\end{gather*} 
and 
\begin{gather*} p \Vdash \dot{f}:\theta \longrightarrow trcl(\{\tau\}) \ \text{is a surjection}
\end{gather*} 
For each $\alpha < \theta$ let $B_{\alpha} =  \{ q \in Fn(\kappa,2) \ | \ \exists \pi \in H_{\xi}\cap V^{\mathbb{P}}  \ \& \ q \leq p \ \& \ q \Vdash \pi \in \rho \ \& \check{\pi} = \dot{f}(\alpha) \} $ and $A_{\alpha} \subseteq B_{\alpha} \cup \{ q \in Fn(\kappa,2) \ |  \ q \perp p \} $ a maximal antichain.   For each $ \alpha < \theta $ and $ q \in A_{\alpha} \cap B_{\alpha}$ pick $ t(\alpha,q) \in H_{\xi}$ such that $q \Vdash t(\alpha,q) \in \rho \ \& \  \check{t(\alpha,q)} = \dot{f}(\alpha)$. 
\begin{gather*} \sigma:= \{ (\pi,q) \ | \exists \alpha,q ( \alpha < \theta  \ \& \ q \in A_{\alpha} \cap B_{\alpha} \ \& \ \pi = t(\alpha,q)) \} 
\end{gather*}  then
\begin{gather*} p \Vdash \sigma = \rho 
\end{gather*}  a contradiction since $ \sigma \in H_{\kappa}$ (This uses $Fn(\kappa,2) \subseteq H_{\kappa}$). 
This gives $ H_{\kappa}[G] = H_{\kappa}^{V[G]}$

> Let $ x \in H_{\kappa}[G]$, then in $V$ there is $ J \subseteq \kappa $ such that $ |J| < \kappa $  and $ x \in V[G_{0}]$ for $ G_{0} = G \cap Fn(J,2)$.

Let $ y \in H_{\kappa} \cap V^{\mathbb{P}}$ such that $ y_{G} = trcl(\{ x\}) $. Then $|trcl(y) \cap Fn(\kappa,2)| < \kappa$, let $ J  = \bigcup\{ dom(r) \ | \ r \in ( trcl(y)\cap Fn(\kappa,2)) \}$

We can then verify by $\in$-induction that $ (\tau,q) \in y$ implies $ \tau_{G} = \tau_{G_{0}}$.  Suppose $(\tau,q) \in y $ and for every $ (\pi,t) \in \tau $  we have $\sigma_{G} = \sigma_{G_{0}}$. Then we have 
\begin{gather*} \tau_{G} =\{ \pi_{G} \ | \ (\pi,t) \in \tau \ \& \ t \in G\} \stackrel{(1)}{=} \{ \pi_{G} \ | \ (\pi,t) \in \tau \ \&  \ t \in G_{0} \}  \stackrel{(2)}{=} \{\pi_{G_{0}} \ | \ (\pi,t) \in \tau \ \& \ t \in G_{0} \} = \tau_{G_{0}}\end{gather*}
where (1) follows from the definition of $ J$ and (2) follows by induction. We can then apply 1.29 from the [link](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~vfischer/Bachelorarbeit2_Schilhan.pdf) cited by @Gödel.